# SPOJ same algorithm accepted in C, Time limit Exceeded in Python

Tags: python, c, algorithm

I am trying to solve the [FCTRL](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL/) problem from SPOJ. The problem is to find the number of trailing zeroes in N! for some T test cases.

```
T ~ 1,00,000.
1 <= N <= 1000000000
```

My problem is very strange. If I try the following C code, it gets accepted with time 0.22 seconds and a memory usage of 1.6M. But if I submit the equivalent Python 3 code, it says Time Limit Exceeded with memory usage of 11M.

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fact_zeros(long int);

int main(void) {
    long int i,t,n;
    if (scanf("%ld",&t) > 0) {
        for (i=1;i<=t;i++) {
            if (scanf("%ld",&n) > 0) {
                fact_zeros(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void fact_zeros(long int N) {
    long int zeros = 0;
    while (N>0) {
        N = N / 5;
        zeros += N;
    }
    printf("%ld\n",zeros);
}
```

Python 3 Code:

```
"""
spoj11Factorial.py
This program calculates the number of zeroes at the 
end of the factorial of each number of the test case.
"""

def fact_zeroes( n ):
    count_5s = 0
    while (n > 0):
        n = n // 5
        count_5s += n
    return count_5s


T = int( input() )
while (T):
  T -= 1
  n = int( input() )
  zeroes = fact_zeroes( n )
  print( zeroes )
```

Can anyone please spot what different / wrong I am doing in the Python code. It works for all given test cases on my machine.

Thanks.

EDIT: Problem Specifications:

```
Added by:   Adrian Kosowski
Date:   2004-05-09
Time limit: 6s
Source limit:   50000B
Memory limit:   256MB
Cluster:    Pyramid (Intel Pentium III 733 MHz)
Languages:  All except: NODEJS PERL 6
Resource:   ACM Central European Programming Contest, Prague 2000
```

Comment: Interpreted Python is considerably slower than compiled C. Have you considered the possibility that this might be all there is to it?

Comment: @NPE Actually yes I thought about it but can the difference be so large?

Comment: @user3154219 How much is "so large"? What is the time limit?

Comment: @interjay Good point. Sorry I should have added. Edited my question to add the information.

Comment: in such calculation intensive a factor 30 is not so surprising you should try an other algorithm

Comment: Presumably you could get a massive speed up with some memoization here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One very easy way to more than double the speed of this program is to convert:

```
n = int( input() )
```

to

```
n = int( raw_input() )
```

Note that [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string from the input, while [input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) runs the Python interpreter on the string after reading it.

On my computer using Python 2.7 this reduces the time from 1.6 seconds to 0.7 seconds

Comment: Wow! Thanks This worked. Time: 2.99 seconds, Memory 4.0M. Does this mean that Python 3 uses more memory as well?

Comment: Nice one! In general I find it quite hard to meet the time limits for programming competitions when using Python especially when using data structures such as segment trees.  Some competitions allow you to use Pypy or psyco which can help a lot - I don't know whether this is the case for SPOJ.

Comment: @Peter: SPOJ is especially nasty in that regard, it's often hard enough to get decent timings with C or C++. Python 2 I/O seems to be much faster than Python 3 I/O on SPOJ as well.